# Tor doesn't receive CSS and JS etc (only locally)

Tags: wordpress, nginx, browser, tor

**When i visit my Wordpress-site locally i fully receive all the content, but if i visit it trough tor, i only receive the HTML.
I am using nginx**

**Code Snippet of the nginx config**

```
upstream wp-php-handler {
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/wordpress/;
    index index.php;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass wp-php-handler;
    }
}
```

**Code Snippet of Torrc**

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

[Image of Tor not receiving content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsdD9.png)